# Analytics: How to detect 32-bit only devices?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, ios

We need to figure out how many of our users are currently running on 32-bit hardware, however iTunesConnect Analytics doesn't break down the devices by:

- Device Model, or
- CPU Architecture

The only breakdowns are by *device family* or *iOS version*. This isn't granular enough.

- An *"iPhone"* device family could be iPhone 5c or iPhone 6. The former is 32-bit, the latter is 64-bit.
- Similarly, an *"iOS version 10"* metric could be iPhone 5c or iPhone 6. The former is 32-bit, the latter is 64-bit.

Can we identify currently active devices that are on 32-bit architecture and would become obsolete purely by using iTunes connect and data Apple supplies without needing to make any code changes to our application?

Comment: It is not a "how to check if device is 32bit" (we can do that easily). It is not a programming question either, since I am not making use of any software stacks for this question.

This is an Apple Development question, regarding their suite of available tools (namely "iTunes Connect" portal). You have a tag for that, which I used, and which describes it pretty well. Other questions in this tag are pretty similar: asking for help in using iTunes Connect.

I could reword the title as "How to check if 32-bit in iTunesConnect", but I thought that was frowned upon if a tag was being used.

Comment: This is totally something I would help get opened / placed for SO. You could ask what API or system information can make this determination within the app. You'd want to put up shell code in your language if you want to get basic model / hardware. Someone is sure to have a library or stub or just help you make an array with all the known 32 bit devices. Apple won't release any more of those, so it's pretty safe to hard code your collection code for profiling your user engagement metrics per device and architecture.

Comment: Legitimate objections to the migration are mentioned on SO, so we will entertain any and all answers that relate to the iTunes connect service and leave stack overflow to handle any code level ways to accomplish this. My apologies for any confusion.